# 2 NICs - selected traffic

Tags: regedit, switching, nic

I recently purchased another NIC for my computer so I could separate LAN-traffic from internet-traffic.
Long story short: **How do I set it up to selectively use a certain NIC?**

I'm using Windows 7 64bit, but am also interested in finding it out for Linux.

So far I found something concerning **regedit** with **RandomAdapter = 1**.

However that doesn't seem to be working as Skype is confused which card to use and general traffic still goes through the same NIC.

I also use a Switch behind my PC and between my router, but I am willing to invest in a... I forgot the 4-letter-combination capable switch that lets me utilize that function.

Could you please share your wisdom with me?
Any help is appreciated!

---

**edit 01:** Accepted solution by Amit:

So do I have to delete ALL routes and then make 2 new ones, one for each NIC ?

route -f

route ADD 192.168.X.IP1 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.X.X METRIC 10

route ADD 192.168.X.IP2 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.X.X METRIC 10

---

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows, this can be set up with the command line utility "route".

Open a command prompt, type `route /?` and go from there...

Comment: I also read something about "use identical metrics", but couldn't find the setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many applications allow you to bind to a specific IP address, see the settings pages.